# how to display editText(for scrolling) fill with String from the firts word, and not from the end?

Tags: android, android-layout

i used edit text for scroll option, and it display text i wrote.
the problem is that when the activity whith this edit text open
it show the text from the end, and i need to scroll up to see the beginig
thans

this is the code (xml):

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="8"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:

    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="Some Long String"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the cursor position in your Activity's onCreate() with setSelection():

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.setSelection(0);
```

---

> i used edit text for scroll option

If you only want to let the user scroll through your text, it is easier to use a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks, the first idea works!!,
but the second with th scrollView didn't..

thank you!